# Atualizar o título jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```
.....
 $sqlContar = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS ContarTeste FROM teste");
 $jmContar = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlContar);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Nome do Site</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        window.setInterval(function() {
            mudarTitulo();
        }, 1000);
        function mudarTitulo() {
            document.title = "("+<?php echo $jmContar->ContarTeste; ?>+") Nome do Site";
        }
       // setTimeout(mudarTitulo(), 1000);
</script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Porém só funciona se eu apertar o F5.

Comment: O PHP é executado apenas uma vez, então não é possível fazer uma nova contagem usando o php dessa forma... o que você pode fazer é mandar uma requisição em ajax para buscar os valores no php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não misture código *javascrit* com *PHP* isso deixa o código fonte muito bagunçado, aprenda sobre [ajax no jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) já que você esta fazendo uso do jQuery.

exemplo deixe seu html assim (ou ainda separe o javascript também):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Nome do Site</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function recursiva(){
            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "suaConsultaMysql.php",
                method: "POST", 
                dataType: "html"
            });

            request.done(function( msg ) {
                window.setInterval(function() {
                    document.title = msg;
                    recursiva();
                }, 1000);
            });
        }
        recursiva();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

No seu arquivo suaConsultaMyslq.php faça:

```
 .....
   $sqlContar = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS ContarTeste FROM teste");
   $jmContar = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlContar);
   echo json_encode($jmContar);
 ?>
```

Comment: Certo SneepS. Tentarei dessa forma. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Eu sempre utilizei window.setInterval e funcionou certinho. Dessa maneira:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.setInterval(function() {
            mudarTitulo();
        }, 1000);
        function mudarTitulo() {
            document.title = "("+<?php echo $jmContar->ContarTeste; ?>+") Nome do Site";
        }
       // setTimeout(mudarTitulo(), 1000);
</script>
```

No entanto você está tentando atualizar uma variável PHP. O PHP é uma linguagem servidor, e é carregada somente uma vez, o javascript é uma linguagem cliente, nesse caso poderia sim ser atualizado para o cliente ver.
Para que o valor da variável PHP seja atualizada, será necessário utilizar AJAX.

Comment: Na verdade o problema está no trecho do php, o php é executado apenas uma vez na página assim não sendo possível obter novos valores dessa forma.

Comment: Certo. É que eu trago a contagem do banco. O PHP pode estar interferindo? Nesse caso, como devo fazer para fazer com que seja automático?

Comment: @Jose.Marcos poste o seu código php para darmos uma olhada

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é por aqui, pois sou novo no site. Criei uma página isolada para testar. Segue abaixo:

```
.....
 $sqlContar = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS ContarTeste FROM teste");
 $jmContar = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlContar);
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Nome do Site</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        window.setInterval(function() {
            mudarTitulo();
        }, 1000);
        function mudarTitulo() {
            document.title = "("+<?php echo $jmContar->ContarTeste; ?>+") Nome do Site";
        }
       // setTimeout(mudarTitulo(), 1000);
</script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Retirei o código PHP e coloquei manualmente e mesmo assim só atualiza quando aperto F5.

Comment: Ah sim, você poderia ter editado a sua pergunta e la mesmo ter colocado junto ;)

Comment: Certo. Desculpe por isso. Já atualizei minha pergunta, porém não consigo remover a minha resposta.